# Can I ask here about nuances of a certain technology?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Essentially, I got confused about a certain behaviour of a well-known API and want to ask whether it does "the thing" "this" or "that" way.

In the help page, it says to not ask anything about "providing support for tools or products" but I think that's not the case. And it doesn't involve any code.

Comment: Maybe to make it a good question (suited for stackoverflow), it should contain at least some example code how the API is called? And if that's the case, leaving the missing code out will not make the question better suited for softwarengineering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the exact question, I would say that what you describe falls into "providing support for tools or products", which is off-topic for Software Engineering. If you are confused about the behavior of an API, you should be contacting the support channels for that API. Alternatively, if you can build a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what you are seeing and what you expect to be seeing, perhaps Stack Overflow can help.